# How can i run all my code in one function

Tags: python, mysql

My python code doesnt work. I get an output for only success mysql connection.
I want to print group id, hostname and other variables. The only output i get is

**('Connected to MySQL Server version ', u'5.7.36-0ubuntu0.18.04.1')
("You're connected to database: ")**

I cannot print group id or anything else. Im a newbie in python :(

```
import os
import mysql.connector
import json


execfile("/home/manager/test/mysqlconnector.py")

active_ip = ""
hostname = ""
group_id = 0

def my_funciton():
 query = "select value_oid from snmp_trap where name_oid = '1.3.6.1.4.1.14823.2.3.3.1.200.1.17.0'"
 cursor = connection.cursor(dictionary=True)
 cursor.execute(query)
 mac = cursor.fetchone()
 mac_string = mac.values()
 mac_str = json.dumps(mac_string) 
 mac_ = mac_str.replace(':','')
 mac_ = mac_.replace('"','')
 mac_ = mac_.replace(']','')
 mac_ = mac_.replace('[','')  
 return mac_

 active_mac = my_function()

 query = "select epp_active_ip, epp_hostname, epp_group_id from epp_inventory where epp_active_mac = + 'active_mac.upper()'"
 cursor = connection.cursor(dictionary=True)
 cursor.execute(query)
 rows = cursor.fetchall()
 #active_ip = ""
 #hostname = ""
 #group_id = 0
 for row in rows:
   active_ip = row["epp_active_ip"]
   hostname = row["epp_hostname"]
   group_id = row["epp_group_id"]
   print(group_id)

 query = "select wmic_id from group_wmic where group_id = " + str(group_id)
 cursor = connection.cursor(dictionary=True)
 cursor.execute(query)
 wmic_ids = cursor.fetchall()
 for row in wmic_ids:
    query = "select command_line from wmic_commands where id = " + row["wmic_id"]
    cursor = connection.cursor(dictionary=True)
    cursor.execute(query)
    command_line = cursor.fetchone()

    os.system(command_line)
    os.system("ls -al")




#os.system(command)
my_funciton()
```

Comment: "I get an output for only success mysql connection" what output exactly? Your code doesn't seem to include it. However, you `funciton` function returns after making a bunch of assignments with the `return mac_` statement. All the code underneath it won't get executed.

Comment: I didnt share the code for mysql connection, because it works. How can i execute that part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from naming and indentation issues, which you should really fix, because it will make your code a nightmare to maintain - the issue is quite simple:

Consider:

```
def some_function():
    print('this prints')
    return
    print('this does not')
```

Your code has the exact same problem. In your function `my_funciton`, you have the following line:

```
 return mac_
```

Nothing after that will ever execute. You need to put the return statement in the position of the function's code where you expect it to actually return. You cannot put it just anywhere and expect the function to execute the rest of the code.

Comment: I did what you say but it doesnt work :(

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. I would recommend rewriting / formatting your code so that it meets regular standards (fix the spelling problems, add normal indentation, etc.) - after another look at your code, your problem may be that the indentation in the code you shared is just wrong and that the real problem is that you assign a value to `cursor` in your function, which gets lost as soon as the function returns - you then try to reuse the cursor globally, but nothing is assigned. That would be fixed by adding `global cursor`, but there's nicer ways of doing that.